# Unable to pass data to another component when using `ComponentFactoryResolver` in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my AppComponent - (Parent)

html

```
<button (click)="open()">Dynamically Add Component</button>
```

ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  OpenWindow: any;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {}

 docList = [
    {
      "docType": "ID_PROOF",
      "docTypeDisplay": "ID Proof",
      "documents": {
        "docName": "RSA_DOC",
        "docStatus": "NEW",
        "validUpTO": null,
        "verifiedAt": null,
        "remark": "no remarks here",
        "docValue": "6511265710003",
        "uploadAt": "2020-15-17 09:15:21",
        "docpath": "/docs/folder/imgs",
        "verifiedByUserId": null,
        "verifiedByUserName": null
      }
    }
  ]

  open(): void {
    const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      DynamicWindowComponent
    );
    let componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
    this.OpenWindow = window.open(
      "",
      "childwindow",
      "width=400,height=400,left=150,top=200"
    );
    this.OpenWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "";
    this.OpenWindow.document.body.appendChild(
      componentRef.location.nativeElement
    );
    componentRef.instance.documentList = this.docList;
  }

  close() {
    this.OpenWindow.close();
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to pass `documentList` to the `DynamicWindowComponent` using this line

```
componentRef.instance.documentList = this.docList;
```

But I'm not able to fetch the list on child component.

This is my `DynamicWindowComponent`

html

```
<p>Dynamic Component</p>
<button (click)="close()">Close me!</button>
<hr>
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    Dcoument Type : {{documentList[0].docType}}
</form>
```

ts

```
export class DynamicWindowComponent implements OnInit {
  documentForm: FormGroup;
  documentList;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  close() {
    let existingWin = window.open("", "childwindow");
    existingWin.close();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.documentList);
  }
}
```

Here is a stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzf5bw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);` before open it to make sure it have dirty checked, otherwise, ngOnInit will not be fired, so you can see I can get the list from close click event. See forked [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urxcsf?file=src/app/dynamic-window/dynamic-window.component.ts).